# Getting information about files using node youtube-dl with MeteorJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, youtube-dl

I use node youtube-dl modul with Meteor.js to get information about youtube videos, bc I'm learning to work with Meteor server side, but I get this error I can't solve for half a day. Since youtube-dl is npm modul, can Meteor work with those without further customization?

**Client code:**

```js
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.front.events({
    'click #buttondl': function () {
      // if submited link to input
      if (inputdl.value != '') {
        var link = inputdl.value;
        Meteor.call('information', link);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

**Server code:**

```js
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.methods({
    information: function (link) {
      var youtubedl = Meteor.require('youtube-dl');
      var url = youtubedl(link);

      youtubedl.getInfo(url, function(err, info) {
        if (err) throw err;

        console.log('id:', info.id);
        console.log('title:', info.title);
        console.log('url:', info.url);
        console.log('thumbnail:', info.thumbnail);
        console.log('description:', info.description);
        console.log('filename:', info._filename);
        console.log('duration:', info.duration);
        console.log('format_id:', info.format_id);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

And the error I'm getting:

```js
W20150709-14:35:19.472(-4)? (STDERR) events.js:72
W20150709-14:35:19.472(-4)? (STDERR)         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
W20150709-14:35:19.472(-4)? (STDERR)               ^
W20150709-14:35:19.477(-4)? (STDERR) Error: Command failed:   File "/Users/matejhlavacka/node_modules/youtube-dl/bin/youtube-dl", line 2
W20150709-14:35:19.478(-4)? (STDERR) SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc4' in file /Users/matejhlavacka/node_modules/youtube-dl/bin/youtube-dl on line 3, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
W20150709-14:35:19.478(-4)? (STDERR) 
W20150709-14:35:19.478(-4)? (STDERR)     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:658:15)
W20150709-14:35:19.478(-4)? (STDERR)     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
W20150709-14:35:19.478(-4)? (STDERR)     at maybeClose (child_process.js:766:16)
W20150709-14:35:19.478(-4)? (STDERR)     at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:979:11)
W20150709-14:35:19.478(-4)? (STDERR)     at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
W20150709-14:35:19.479(-4)? (STDERR)     at Pipe.close (net.js:466:12)
```

**EDIT:**

I finally solved it. Instead of [node-youtube-dl](https://github.com/fent/node-youtube-dl) I used basic [python youtube-dl](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md) and this tutorial on [how to execute unix command with Meteor](https://gentlenode.com/journal/meteor-14-execute-a-unix-command/33).

Sample code for getting video description on server is the following:

```js
Meteor.methods({
    information: function (link) {

        exec = Npm.require('child_process').exec;

        runCommand = function (error, stdout, stderr) {
          console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
          console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);

          if(error !== null) {
            console.log('exec error: ' + error);
          }
        }

        exec("youtube-dl --get-description " + link, runCommand);

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It fails probably because you have a python version that is too old, as [documented in the youtube-dl FAQ](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/bf20b9c5405b276e6de29b1b28b2e3ad2182e891/README.md#syntaxerror-non-ascii-character) you need python 2.6 or higher. Upgrading python should solve the issue.

Comment: I have OS X Yosemite that have python 2.7 by defaults, but I reinstalled to Python 2.7.9 and still get the same error.

Comment: That's strange, you should check the output you get when running `python --version` from node.js.

Comment: I've already solved the problem - see Edit in question above.